# How do I draw Q3DSurface axis inside a Qt3DWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

Is it possible to draw axis from the Q3DSurface class inside a Qt3DWindow, so that I cant use the axis and have any geometry and 3D models for example?

Like the picture from the example below, but suppose I want to place a cube or a 3d model inside the graph space.

I want to have both the 3d model and the graph axis in the same 3D space, so that if I rotate or zoom, both the model and the graph rotate and zoom.

In other words, I want the QtDataVisualization axis functionality but I won't show data, but 3D models, and I want the axis for scale and reference.

[image]

Comment: You mean Q3DSurface, don't you? I don't think this is possible. When you look at the class Q3DSurface you see that it inherits from QWindow. There is no inheritance from any class that could be used in Qt3D. You could of course write your own axis visualization.

Comment: May I ask some more words on how to proceed to write the axis visualization?